# Regular expression to find and replace specific value from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, expression

I am trying to extract ?ref value from a URL and wanted to replace it with some other value.

Example Lets say my URL is something like this http://myexample.com/?ref=test?nref=xml&page=1 or it can be http://myexample.com/?fref=like?ref=test?nref=xml&page=1

From the above url I wanted to find ?ref value and wanted to replace it from another string say "testing". Any help and also wanted to learn advance Regular expressions any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Why do you have more than one "?" in the url ?

Comment: It can be its just an example.

Comment: Lets say there is only one ? then what would be the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for your posted examples.

```
str = str.replace(/\b(ref=)[^&?]*/i, '$1testing');
```

Regular expression:

```
\b             the boundary between a word char (\w) and and not a word char
 (             group and capture to \1:
  ref=         'ref='
 )             end of \1
[^&?]*         any character except: '&', '?' (0 or more times)
```

The `i` modifier is used  for case-insensitive matching.

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/70263)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have two "?" in url.   I assume you mean
http://myexample.com?ref=test&nref=xml&page=1

you can use the function below

here url is your url, name is the key, in your case it is "ref", and the new_value is the new value, i.e. the value that would replace "test"

the function will return the new url

```
function replaceURLParam (url, name, new_value) {

  // ? or &, name=, anything that is not &, zero or more times          
  var str_exp = "[\?&]" + name + "=[^&]{0,}";

  var reExp = new RegExp (str_exp, "");

  if (reExp.exec (url) == null) {  // parameter not found
      var q_or_a = (url.indexOf ("?") == -1) ? "?" : "&";  // ? or &, if url has ?, use &
      return url + q_or_a + name + "=" + new_value;
  }

  var found_string = reExp.exec (url) [0];

  // found_string.substring (0, 1) is ? or &
  return url.replace (reExp, found_string.substring (0, 1) + name + "=" + new_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var name = 'ref', 
    value = 'testing',
    url;

url = location.href.replace(
    new RegExp('(\\?|&)(' + name + '=)[^&]*'), 
    '$1$2' + value
);
```

`new RegExp('(\\?|&)(' + name + '=)[^&]*')` gives `/(\?|&)(ref=)[^&]*/` which means :

```
"?" or "&" then "ref=" then "everything but '&' zero or more times".
```

Finally, `$1` holds the result of `(\?|&)` while `$2` holds the result of `(ref=)`.

Links to read : [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [regexp](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml).